# Javascript Date Format not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, date

So I'm trying to fix a javascript countdown timer. It works in chrome and safari but it doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer. It is to do with how the date is formatted, more so the timezone.

I have it working when it's hard coded but I need to implement it into the existing code, which gets the data from a server. In the Javascript code provided, in the timeString line, when I remove the timezone variable and add 'T' in the empty space between the Month and hours variables it works in all. the only problem is I'm trying to get it to work with the var timezone included.

///Hmtl Code

///

```
var Year = '2020';
var Month = '08';
var Day = '7';
var Hour = '04';
var Minute = '45';
var Timezone = 'GMT-5';
```

///Javascript Code

///Variables getting Initialized
///

```
Year = typeof Year == 'undefined' ? null : Year;
Month = typeof Month == 'undefined' ? null : Month;
Day = typeof Day == 'undefined' ? null : Day;
Hour = typeof Hour == 'undefined' ? null : Hour;
Minute = typeof Minute == 'undefined' ? null : Minute;
Timezone = typeof Timezone == 'undefined' ? 'GMT-5': Timezone;
```

///

///timestring
///

```
timeString = Year + '-' + Month + '-' + Day + ' ' + Hour + ':' + Minute  + ':00 ' + Timezone;
```

///

So This works it only works in chrome and safari. In Firefox and IE it comes back with NaN or invalid date. What I'm looking for help with is getting the correct date/ time format to work in all browsers.

Comment: So it produces `2020-08-7 04:45:00 GMT-5` which is not an ISO 8601 format

Comment: What is `Hmtl Code` and why is there none?

Comment: `new Date("2020-08-07T16:45:00-05:00")`

Comment: timeString = timerYear + '-' + timerMonth + '-' + timerDay + 'T' + timerHour + ':' + timerMinute  + ':00 ' + timerTimezone;

Comment: that's what I changed it to but it doesn't work in any browsers

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered constructing a JavaScript date and then handling it as an object?

> It works in chrome and safari but it doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer

This has been tested in Firefox, IE11 and Chrome:

```
function createDate(year, month, day, hour, minute, offset) {
    // adjusts for time zone
    var nudgeHours = 0;
    try {
        nudgeHours = -1 * parseInt(offset.substring(3), 10); // chomp after 'GMT'; fix offset for GMT
    } catch(e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }
    // construct and return a GMT date, making sure to accommodate for milliseconds in our nudgeHours
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute) + (nudgeHours*60*60*1000));
}
```

Then you can manipulate this date as you need to without worrying about parsing differences between browsers.

```
console.log("Before: " + timeString);

console.log("After: " + createDate(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Timezone));
```

Output:

```
Before: 2020-08-7 04:45:00 GMT-5
After: Fri Aug 07 2020 05:45:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

> So I'm trying to fix a javascript countdown timer

Without the timer logic, it's hard to know where the counting is occuring (and thus hard to know why the above format was chosen), but handling it as a `Date(...)` object should also decrease the likelihood of breaking on any non-standard date arithmetic.

As a word of caution, `GMT-5` is a bit suspiciously formatted.  For example, IST is `+5:30`, so the `nudgeHours` makes an assumption that the `GMT-5` is a custom format that the countdown timer was already coded against and not a standardized format.  To that point, IST would have to be `GMT+5.5` for the above logic to continue working correctly.

Comment: The variables are already predefined on the server. And I got it to work on Chrome and IE by changing the format of the timeString but it still doesn't work in firefox, getting the NaN back. It's weird cause its the same format as the hard code which worked in all of the browsers but when i replicate it in timeString it doesn't work in firefox.

Comment: `NaN` suggests an arithmetic operator couldn't find a number.  JavaScript can be very implicit, so you may want to double check any `+` operators, specifically around strings and vars.

Comment: timeString = Month + '-' + Day + '-' + Year + ' ' + Hour + ':' + Minute  + ':00 ' + Timezone;

Comment: thats what i have and it looks correct .... why is this only happening in firefox .. why not the other browsers.

Comment: There's no code in the original post that fails on Firefox.  Perhaps you're missing a function call in your example?

Comment: Well I haven't added in all of the code because a lot more .... but this is exactly where the problem is coming from though.

Comment: The following code (exact copy of yours) works in Firefox.  I strongly feel that you are missing something in your example. https://jsfiddle.net/0pvqzLuf/

Comment: yes well it works when you console log it but when i put the timeString into my countdown timer function it comes back with invalid date

Comment: Without the countdown timer code, assisting with the symptom you are describing is extremely difficult.  Can you please provide the countdown timer code?